# recursively cat a vector in Eigen

Tags: vector, eigen, cat

I have an Eigen Vector. I would want to cat it recursively. For example

```
 Eigen::Vector3d vec;
 vec << 5, 6, 7;
 Eigen::VectorXd vecCat;
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
      vecCat << vec(i),0,0;
 cout<<vecCat<<endl;
```

so that the final output would be 
vecCat= 5 0 0 6 0 0 7 0 0

I am getting an error if I do the above way. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If i not mistaken, in Eigen you cannot fill vector by "<<" partially. Only way which i see is to use simple for loop and []/() operators

Comment: @Dark_Daiver well, in theory one can, but you would need to store the return value of the `CommaInitializer` in a variable (I'm not elaborating on this, since this is not intended and not guaranteed to be future proof). And as you said, it is much easier with a loop and `[]` operator. (Alternatively, storing it in a 3x3 temporary matrix and mapping that back to a vector)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on both the solutions you proposed? I am not able to understand clearly also I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, I will not explain how one could use the `CommaInitializer` iteratively. But here is a solution using `Eigen::Map`:

```
Eigen::Vector3d vec;
vec << 5,6,7;
Eigen::VectorXd vecCat = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(9); // result vector
{
    // map vector to 3x3 matrix:
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> map(vecCat.data(), 3,3);
    map.row(0) = vec.transpose(); // set top elements to elements of vec
}
std::cout << vecCat.transpose() << '\n';
```

If `row(0)` is everything you need to modify in `map` you can alternatively (instead of the `{ }` block) write:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd::Map(vecCat.data(), 3, 3).row(0) = vec.transpose();
```

Comment: Thanks chtz that was indeed very helpful